# Fetching data from firebase realtime database returns invalid json response

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase-realtime-database, fetch, next.js

Here I am making a fetch request to an api -

```
export async function getServerSideProps(ctx) {
    let id = ctx.params.id;

    let userObject;
    let userId;
    const cookie = parseCookies(ctx);
    if (cookie.auth) {
        userObject = JSON.parse(cookie.auth);
        userId = userObject.id;
    }
    if (!userId) {
        return {
            redirect: {
                permanent: false,
                destination: '/',
            },
        };
    }


    const res = await fetch(`http://localhost:3000/api/tests/${id}`);
    console.log(await res.json());
    const data = await res.json();
    console.log(data);
    // return {
    //  props: { product: data },
    // };
    return {
        props: {},
    };
}
```

Here I am reading data from firebase realtime database -

```
export default async (req, res) => {
    const { id } = req.query;
    console.log(id);
    let obj;

    firebase
        .database()
        .ref('/test/' + id)
        .once('value')
        .then(snapshot => {
            console.log('here');
            const data = snapshot.val();
            obj = data;
        })
        .then(() => res.status(200).json(obj))
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
};
```

Which gives me this error -

`Server Error FetchError: invalid json response body at https://localhost:3000/api/tests/-MUT5-DbK6Ff6CstPSGc reason: Unexpected end of JSON input`

Everything seems to work except the json response I am getting after making fetch request. I can't even console.log to see what response I am actually getting. What am I missing?

Edit - Here's my firebase database structure, where test node is root node

[image]

Comment: What do you get when making the request in Postman?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no return in your promise. That's why obj is null. Instead of then just send the response in first capture.

```
export default async (req, res) => {
    const { id } = req.query;
    console.log(id);
    let obj;

    firebase
        .database()
        .ref('/test/' + id)
        .once('value')
        .then(snapshot => {
            console.log('here');
            const data = snapshot.val();
            obj = data;
            res.status(200).json(obj)
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
};
```